# why i can't get adb shell top works?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm testing an android app by my PC. I try to catch the CPU usage of it.
if I use
*adb shell top -m 10 |tee aa.txt*
it works fine. 
but if i modify it like this
*adb shell top -m 10 |grep myAPPname|tee aa.txt*
it can not. Why and how to make it work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the command below:

```
while true; do
  adb shell top -m 10 -n 1 | grep kso >> aa
done
```

`-n` means only show the current status instead of updating frequently.

However, I suggest you use Android Profiler which is a built-in function in Android Studio to achieve your monitoring work.

Comment: Thanks, -n works . yeah, maybe Android Profiler will get a better work.